# wsl' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Windows Subsystem for Linux and turned it on under windows turn ON OFF features. And then restarted my Pc. I did check on cmd soon after restarting the PC by typing "wsl" and it works. But when i run my script from its folder which has the command "wsl -e xxx.sh", i get an error

> 'wsl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Could you guys help me with it please. Thank you.

**My PC is running on**
Os: Windows 10 Pro;
Microsoft windows version: 1903;
Os Build: 18362.418

Comment: Did you try using `wsl.exe` instead?

Comment: Yes tried now still no luck. Now i get the error as "'wsl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Is your script clobbering the PATH?  That is the only logical answer that I can think of.  AND.. from CMD.EXE, you don't EVER need to add ".exe".

Comment: Yes @SeñorCMasMas i do believe wsl.exe is not required to be added. just wsl works fine. On normal command line if i type wsl and hit enter, i get ubuntu terminal window

Comment: 1.  echo %PATH% from the command line (when it works)
2.  echo %PATH% somewhere from within your script.  Add a pause statement after if you need to (when it doesn't).  3.  Compare the two paths.
  You will probably find your answer there.

Comment: Using %path% as a variable in a script to refer to some arbitrary folder is a classic mistake.

Comment: I saw the difference. from point 1 and 2 you mentioned i see the ubuntu path as "C:\Users\Administrator\Ubuntu" and from within the script "C:\Users\Administrator\Ubuntu xxx.sh" But what might have gone wrong in here?

Comment: Are you setting a variable called %path% in your script?

Comment: In order to properly answer this question the following information must be provided.  What version of Windows 10 are you running?  You can use **winver** to determine this vital information.  If you are running 1909 you need to indicate if you are running WSL 1 or WSL 2.  Likewise, we need to know what your full system path variable is, provide all this information as an edit to your question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reason why a command which runs an executable program works on the command line, but not in a batch script, is that, in the script, prior to the line containing the problem command, the user has created a variable %path%. It might seem a handy name for a variable that holds, well, a *path*. The problem is that this variable name is used by Windows to hold a semicolon-separated list of folders which are searched when an executable is called. It is a **system variable**. If you have redefined it, then all executables (e.g. .exe, .bat, .vbs, etc) that Windows uses, will not be found, and the script will fail with exactly this message, where xxx  is the program or file that is expected:

`'xxx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

This can be confusing because commands which are *internal* to the cmd environment (dir, cls, set, copy, move, etc) (list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)) still continue to work in this situation.

You can debug a script where this is suspected by inserting the `path` command immediately before a problem line. The Windows path variable starts with these folders, and may be extended as programs are installed:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`

Comment: Hi, I check the PATH under Windows path variable, it already had the path %SystemRoot%\system32
So i went back to my script and specified the full path as **"wsl -e C:/Users/<user>/setup/xxx.sh"** and it worked!
Might be silly of me but i realized that the windows linux subsystem command **wsl** was not able to find the script.
And specifying the full path did the trick. Thank you guys for your valuable time to help. Much appreciate it.

Comment: I would add a suggestion to check the variables: windir, SystemDrive, ComSpec, are present, otherwise I would add them, just a tip ..

Answer (score 15):

Common problem when trying to access 64-bit tools from 32-bit processes. `wsl.exe` is in `System32`. But if your script happens to run as a 32-bit process, then all accesses to `System32` are redirected to `SysWOW64`. In order to access `wsl.exe` in the "real" `System32` folder, you'll have to use `Sysnative` instead, like in `C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I had to recompile my app with proper x86_64 architecture to fix the issue.

Comment: `set path=%path%;C:\Windows\Sysnative` fixed the issue for me. I wonder why `C:\Windows\Sysnative` is not in the `path` by default.

Comment: I was trying to run wsl from Vim and this works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This error is covered in the "Troubleshooting installation" section of the [WSL installation guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10):

> **The term 'wsl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program.**
>
> Ensure that the Windows Subsystem for Linux Optional Component is
> installed. Additionally, if you are using an ARM64 device and running
> this command from PowerShell, you will receive this error. Instead run
> wsl.exe from PowerShell Core, or Command Prompt.

Comment: This was my case I didn't realized about the 32/64 jump there and when using `powershell.exe` I couldn't make it work so got `pwsh` installed using choco and then ran the `wsl` commands as follow

`pwsh.exe -NoProfile -Command 'wsl --set-default-version 2'`

Thanks,

Comment: This is the only sane response and should be marked as accepted, the one that is curently accepted is nothing but the quora style drivel by someone who is building their stack overflow profile.

Comment: I'm not using an ARM64 device (I'm using AMD Ryzen) but this answer still solved my problem.  The command fails in PowerShell, but it works perfectly fine in a Command Prompt.  Weird.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ENV:PATH="$ENV:PATH;c:\Windows\System32"
```

usando esse comando ele vai achar o wsl no path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).